# Sharepoint 2010 Creating a content editor webpart with prepopulated content

Tags: 2010, content-editor-web-part

Working on a site in Sharepoint 2010. I have created a custom page layout with a content editor webpart inside a webpart zone. I want to be able to have the same content appear within the content editor every time a user initially creates a page with this layout. They should have the option to change out the content as needed, but I wanted to have some default content already in the editor upon page creation. Is it possible to prepopulate a content editor webpart in the layout when a user creates a page?

Answer (score 0):

I, like you, was looking for an answer to this.  I did finally find it [on this MSDN article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f5aeb72-1b94-4411-8846-02c5229230bd/how-to-make-default-content-in-content-editor-web-part-editable-when-created-from-template?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious), but in a roundabout way, so I'll explain it a little better.

When you add the CEWP using SharePoint Designer (making an assumption here), there is a  property that gets added, which has a tag inside, .  You need to insert a  tag inside the CDATA brackets.  You can then nest whatever HTML you need inside of the value tag.  See below.

```
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>My Pre-populated Webpart</Title>
  <FrameType>None</FrameType>
  <Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <PartOrder>2</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties>
  <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
  <ID>g_8a6ddad9_b2c2_4db6_824b_deac70c5f009</ID>
  <ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
                    <Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[<VALUE>
        <h1>PREOPULATED TEXT AND STUFF HERE</h1>
  </VALUE]]></Content>
  <PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
</WebPart>
```

I know it is a late response, but I hope it helps you, or since it was the first in my results list when I was searching, maybe it will help someone else.